Is truth independent of the human mind?
I claim that all things that are perceived to exist are either an illusion, a construction of the mind, or exist in-and-of-themselves.
I disagree with the pragmatist and cultural relativist arguments that truth is a mental construct. Richard Rorty argues,
“[Pragmatism is] the ethnocentric view that there is nothing to be said about either truth or rationality apart from descriptions of the familiar procedures of justification which a given society-ours-uses in one or another area of inquiry.”
Human perceptions are not inherently objective. Yet our perception of something is what we believe it to be. So if truth is a mental construct, it should be based on how we perceive or mentally experience it.
My argument is the following:

All things we perceive to exist are either an illusion, created, or self-existent.

By illusion, I mean 'fake'; something we perceive to exist but does not, externally.
By created, I mean subject to causality; it exists because it is made by something else, or results as a consequence of something.
By self-existent, I mean foundational; not subject or contingent upon something else.


Truth cannot be an illusion, since to state as much would be self-defeating.

Truth cannot be 'created,' because that as well would be self-defeating.

Truth cannot be a mental construct, because then it would vary from person to person based on their beliefs. Thus, for example, the truth of the Japanese would differ greatly from the truth of the Americans. It would be necessarily impossible to translate between the languages, as the cultures never intersected, and there would be no relation of truth. Space and time would likely vary between each separate culture. Evidently, none of this is true. It is possible to translate between each language. Space and time remain the same regardless of belief system.


If someone were to argue humans do have the same mental construct of truth even cross-culturally because humans share the same cognitive structure, then they would not be arguing for a relativistic position for truth, but would be implying that there is a self-existent concept of truth which the human mind is tailored to make use of.

The only option left, as per the trilemma, would be that truth is necessarily self-existent.


So does truth necessarily exist in and of itself, prior to any causation or explainability?

In analytic philosophy truth is made by a truth-maker and received by truth-bearer...

@philosophyisgreat123 If you give your definition of "truth" this could improve your post. - In general, "true" or "false" is a property of a proposition. Then "a truth" is one true proposition.

Maybe you are conflating Truth with Facts.

"The ultimate goal of my argument is to equate truth with God" It seems like your argument gets you to a version of "God" that doesnt require most features we consider "Godlike".  Like this "God" only has the properties of being "necessarily self-existent".  Does anyone define God as "something which is necessarily self-existent"?  It seems like a really weak definition of God that no one is really talking about when they say "God".

'Is truth self-evident?' might have been a Question people could work on.
I suggest 'Is truth self-existent?' has no more meaning in English than 'Is truth existent?'
Doe anyone doubt that?

"if truth is created, it is created by human perceptions" - I wonder if you're getting confused between Truth and Theories of Truth.  Human theories of gravity are created by perceptions, but that doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as gravitation being a human creation.

"We know that all things we perceive to exist are either an illusion, created, or self-existent." is an unfounded assertion. A three parts variant of the false dichotomy fallacy. No, we do not know that.


If truth is created, then it is the result of belief.

Not necessarily.  Axiomatic Theories of Truth propose that one way of thinking about truth is that True, as a predicate that correctly applies to some subset of the things that exist, does not necessarily need to have beliefs or meanings as its objects, but rather that what counts is that the different true things stand in particular kinds of relation to one another, understood as logic.
Semantic theories of truth propose that True connects to things that are linguistic or propositional (like intentional states), and we generally evaluate axiomatic theories in the understanding that their intended models are really semantic (this helps us formulate more mathematically rich semantic theories of truth).
But this need not be constitutive of what it takes for something to be a Truth predicate or property - Truth might well apply to rocks that just happen by chance to exemplify the relationships described by the axiomatic structures it lays out.  A Calculus, if you like. Hoho.

You ask:

Is truth self-existent?

Well, first, you have to understand that there the term truth is polysemous. That's the fancy word linguists use to describe words with generally close, but distinct meanings. In philosophy, we can talk about personal truths, contingent truths, correspondent truths, coherent truths, and so on. So it's important in your philosophical deliberations to recognize that truth has many different aspects.
In order to familiarize yourself with those different truths, look for different theories of truth. According to WP, here's an introductory list of major theories of truth to get you started. The important fact to recognize as you hone your thoughts about truth is to move from folk notions to technical notions of truth. The fastest way to do that is to review the canonical literature of truth that goes back to the Ancient Greeks, no small task.
One important theory of truth is a semantic theory that is predicated upon it and is called the semantic theory of truth. Advanced by the great Polish logician Tarski who was instrumental in creating modern notions of logic and language, it's about how one language or linguistic context helps us to decide if another claim in another context is true or not. In modern times, some thinkers, like Davidson believe that the meaning of a sentence IS its truth value, an idea advocated by truth-conditional semantics.
To answer your question in the spirit of modern philosophical thinkers who believe in a psychological origin, truth is a construct of the human mind. The topologist Brouwer was an advocate of intuitionism which advocates that mathematics and truth are created by the mind. That is, truth is a byproduct of human judgement, an important idea advocated earlier by the philosophical psychologist and would-be Catholic priest turned scholar. From the SEP article on Brentano's Theory of Judgement (SEP):

Judgements are one of the three basic kinds of intentional phenomena with which Brentano deals at great length in his Psychology. That is not to say, however, that Brentano’s theory of judgement is just concerned with psychological issues. Brentano also aims to show how an experience of judging, specifically the experience of judging correctly, can provide us with a basis for grasping concepts like existence, truth, and logical inference.

In this view, truth is simply a way of expressing that we have engaged in good judgement. A truth that corresponds to the state of affairs in the world is a good judgement about physical reality. A truth that coheres to another truth is good judgement. A truth that functions for a person's attempt to explain the world around them is a personal truth, and so on. On this view, truth is a byproduct of psychological process of the mind and does not exist independent of it.


Truth cannot be an illusion, since to state as much would be self-defeating.

This sounds like an attempted refutation of the deflationary account of truth. But it is unclear to me exactly how it should be interpreted in the context of deflationism. Deflationism typically revolves around some version of the so-called "equivalence schema," which (usually) looks like this:

For every [sentence/proposition] p: "p is true" if and only if p.

The precise interpretation of this schema depends on the variety of deflationism in use, but there is nothing obviously self-defeating about defining "true" in this manner. It is logically coherent to assert that e.g. "'Snow is white' is true if and only if snow is white."

I come to the question of 'What is truth' with only the knowledge that it exists and is primarily metaphysical. Kant says in his Critique of Pure Reason, “It must be utterly absurd to ask for a mark of the truth…a sufficient, and at the same time universal, test of truth cannot possibly be found.” We could say that truth is that which corresponds to reality; but this basically means 'Truth is truth'. In any ways, this is a controversial definition of truth.

This is not much of an objection, frankly. It basically amounts to "deflationism is trivial." The problem with that is, "trivial" is not the same thing as "wrong." You need to articulate why truth cannot be trivial, and this argument simply does not do that.


If truth is created, then it is the result of belief.

Where does this statement come from?

If belief determines truth, then truth would vary from belief to belief.

This conflates different meanings of the word belief.

It is possible to translate between each language.

It is possible to make approximations of the basic meaning behind the words in one language and communicate this in the other, but the word 'translate' does not mean to draw a direct parallel. People speaking different languages have different ideas behind each concept, each word has different connotations, and between regions and even speakers there are differences in interpretation of the language which does separate the idea of truth.
Is there anything else that I missed?
